# Calling htlatex on a document whose filename has spaces

Tags: tex4ht

I'm trying to build a document with `htlatex` to output an `.odt` file, but the filename of my document has spaces. And, as `htlatex` takes three sets of arguments between quotes, I can't seem to find the syntax for it to receive a filename with spaces.

I've tried:

```
htlatex my\ document.tex "xhtml,ooffice" " -cmozhtf" " -coo"
htlatex 'my document.tex' "xhtml,ooffice" " -cmozhtf" " -coo"
htlatex "my document.tex" "xhtml,ooffice" " -cmozhtf" " -coo"
```

all to no avail.

Are spaces really not well taken here? Or am I missing something obvious?

---

I'm running a Linux Mint machine and issuing the command in the same directory `my document.tex` resides, on which I have permissions.

Considering that if I run `pdflatex "my document.tex"` everything works fine as expected, I'm assuming this is something specific to `htlatex` command syntax, and thus (unless my assumption proves wrong), on topic.

The critical portion of the error is:

> ```
> ! I can't find
> file `my'.
> ```

Comment: In all cases, the critical line is "! I can't find file `my'." (I can insert the full error message if it might be useful).

Comment: It does accept `"\"my document.tex\""` initially, but than latter in the process compilation is broken with error "--- error --- Can't find/open file 'document.dvi'" As to your point, you may be right, but `htlatex` is a wrapper and the arguments it receives are sent to its other commands.

Comment: spaces really aren't supported by `tex4ht`. I can try to add support to `make4ht`, but it is still safer to avoid them.

Comment: @michal.h21 If this is indeed the case, avoid the spaces I will. But I wanted to be sure I was not the source of the problem, thus the question. If you'd like to convert your comment as an answer, I'll happily accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit: I've fixed this issue in the development version of [make4ht](https://github.com/michal-h21/make4ht)

---

`htlatex` doesn't have support for spaces by default. It is just a shell or batch script, depending on the operating system, which calls number of other programs, each of may have different handling of spaces in filenames and their escaping. As Coby suggested, you can try to run

```
htlatex "\"my document.tex\"" "xhtml,ooffice" " -cmozhtf" " -coo"
```

This will fail with

```
tex4ht -f/"my 
  document.tex" 
  -i~/tex4ht.dir/texmf/tex4ht/ht-fonts/ 
  -cmozhtf 
--- warning --- Can't find/open file `document.dvi'
--- error --- Can't find/open file `document.dvi'
```

You can try to run the `tex4ht` command directly:

```
tex4ht -cmozhtf "my document.dvi"
```

This seems to work. The next step is to run the `t4ht` command, which will pack the intermediate files to a resulting ODT file:

```
t4ht -coo "my document.dvi"
```

This command runs lot of external commands and it fails big time:

```
System call: mkdir sxw-my document.dir       
mkdir: adresář „sxw-my“ nelze vytvořit: File exists
--- Warning --- System return: 256 
...
system call: mv    "my document"-styles.4oy         sxw-my document.dir/styles.xml
mv: cíl 'document.dir/styles.xml' není adresářem        
--- Warning --- System return: 256
...
mv: nelze získat informace o 'document.odt': No such file or directory
--- Warning --- System return: 256
```

This means that  no matter of escaping, spaces cannot work for the ODT output and it is better to avoid them.

BTW, it is better to use [make4ht](https://ctan.org/pkg/make4ht?lang=en) for the `tex4ht` invocation, it has many additional features, like direct support for the ODT output, using

```
make4ht -f odt filename.tex
```

It can also support the filenames with spaces using small trick. Save the following file as `my_build.mk4`:

```
local escaped = settings.input:gsub(" ", "_")
set_settings {latex_par = '-jobname=' ..escaped, tex_file = '"' ..settings.tex_file ..'"', input = escaped }
```

It replaces spaces with underscores in the generated filenames, so it works with all called commands. Call it using

```
make4ht -f odt -e my_build.mk4 "my document.tex"
```

Comment: @gusbrs I've just documented my investigation, I think that I should add support for spaces in `make4ht`, so I am quite happy that I've found a solution which shouldn't require rewritting lot of code

Comment: Well, as I told you I'm also investigating. :) Btw, is there any place you could point me to, where I can find known issues for `tex4ht` (like, "don't use filenames with spaces", "don't use makecell")?

Comment: @gusbrs you can find a issue tracker and mailing list here: https://www.tug.org/tex4ht/ but most active source is [tex4ht tag here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tex4ht)

Comment: I've been following the tag for some time. For this is a relevant bottleneck in my LaTeX workflow, given I frequently need an `.odt` (or similar) for submission. I'd tried once before, but did not succeed, so here I am trying again. Let's hope I make it this time for, in my view, `tex4ht` is the only viable option for the purpose. Thanks again for the pointers.

Comment: @gusbrs I've just added support for spaces in filenames to the development version of `make4ht`

Comment: @gusbrs it will take some time before it reach CTAN, I want also to fix the ODT issues. but I would be happy if you could try it and test it, if everything works correctly

Comment: michal I'll gladly do so. But I wouldn't be sure how to install it. As far as I've looked, tex4ht files are somewhat scattered through the TeX Live tree. Could you give me some tips on the matter? (or a pointer where this could be found).

Comment: @gusbrs `make4ht` uses just Lua files, it is easiest to install it  using `make install`

Comment: michal I eventually tried it from what I found in https://github.com/michal-h21/make4ht/blob/master/INSTALL.md. As I'm not really proficient in this matters I followed the instructions to the letter. But, even though I have everything in my users path, that's not so for `sudo`, so the installation got lost (`latexmk` and `kpsewhich`  not found, this last one resulting in installation on root...)(already fixed, don't worry, but I suggest the removal of `sudo` from the instructions, we can safely assume the user has permissions for TEXHOME, I suppose.

Comment: But I managed to install, testing under way. ;)

Comment: michal Two issues thus far. If non ascii characters are involved, compilation fails. Second is that `filename with spaces.tex` will generate `filename_with_spaces.bcf` thus fooling biber when it needs to run. The same is true for all aux files. `make4ht` knows the name substitution, but other programs which may eventually be called in during build, don't (at least as most editors would deal with file names).

Comment: @gusbrs I've changed the makefile and installation instructions to avoid sudo

Comment: @gusbrs can you make an mwe with these issues? it is necessary to replace spaces with underscores, so subsequent commands should be called with changed name. it is possible to use the build file to call `biber` etc, this should fix these issues

Comment: As to the makefile, I'd suggest you condition to `kpsewhich` being found (though, I'm not sure, probably avoiding sudo is enough, as if it is not found, the `cp`s will try to write to root and won't have permission). But, let me ask, should we continue on chat or on the issue page of `make4ht` at GitHub?

Comment: MWE for non ascii characters: https://gist.github.com/gusbrs/b44e840c865b752e6834a8e0e4fba138

Comment: MWE for bibliography: https://gist.github.com/gusbrs/764ca695adecf33ec5d8e8b0c4a68c19

Comment: @gusbrs I think it would be best to move the discussion to `make4ht` Github, it will be easier to track the discussion. I will be mostly offline for the weekend, so I am not sure when I will be able to look at these issues

Comment: I'll open an issue there then.

Comment: @gusbrs I think I've fixed the issue with accented filenames

Comment: Great! Thanks once again! I posted details at GitHub, in the issue you had already opened. As to timing, please take your time, of course. I wouldn't choose to navigate these waters on a deadline (and, even if I did, that would be on me).

Comment: Hi, comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78693/discussion-on-answer-by-michal-h21-calling-htlatex-on-a-document-whose-filename). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be due to `htlatex` being unable to correctly tokenize the filename, when it contains spaces.

Adding in an additional pair of escaped quotes (i.e. `"\"<file>\""`) should fix this:

```
htlatex "\"my document.tex\"" "xhtml,ooffice" " -cmozhtf" " -coo"
```

Comment: Thank you. But, as mentioned in the comment above, it helps, but does not appear to solve the problem.

Comment: @gusbrs In that case, It looks like it cannot properly handle files with spaces. I suggest contacting the maintainer and using filenames without spaces for now.